# android setOnMenuItemClickListener not called

Tags: android, menu

Inside of my onCreateOptionsMenu function I implemented this:

```
          mymenuitem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener(){
           public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
            update_freq=1;
            showChosen();  (some user defined function)
            update_time();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

However, the .setOnMenuItemClickListener only be called the first time I click my preference, later on when I went back to menu and click preference buttons, it never be called.
can anyone tell me what is the problem? My menu is written in xml file and inflated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to override `onOptionsItemSelected`. The OnMenuItemClickListener is set on a single, specific MenuItem.

Comment: I tried override onOptionsItemSelected, the same result as this one. The first time choose options it works, then later when I go back and click the option, it does not work any more.